# Where to download ui.jqgrid-bootstrap.css from?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jqgrid

I want to use Guriddo jqGrid JavaScript 5.0  which is recently released and download ui.jqgrid-bootstrap.css but I failed to find it in the internet. I also can't find its cdn.. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You can download it here: http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103292

Or, you can find CDN here: https://cdnjs.com/libraries/jqgrid

Also check out this GitHub repository: https://github.com/Soliman/jqGrid.bootstrap

Comment: As mentioned in the comment, this cdn url works https://cdnjs.com/libraries/jqgrid.
But unable to load first url http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103292.